# Can I interact with a smart-contract that's a variable inside another smart-contract?

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, contract-invocation

I want to interact with a third party contract.

I can interact with (third party) Smart Contract A.

Inside Smart Contract A's code is

```
import { contractb } from ".../ContractB.sol";

ContractB public contractb;
```

some functions inside Contract A interact with contractb by using something like

```
contractb.function();
```

I would like to interact with a function that is available inside contractb. Can I do this, or would this only be possible if Contract A is calling the function in one of it's functions?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's right!You can use another contract within a contract.

Solidity is influenced by the C++, Python and Javascript languages，A lot of syntax is similar.

The following code works correctly，You can use it as a reference

```
contract Test {

    ContractA public contractA = new ContractA();

    function test() public view returns (bool){
        return contractA.contractB().test();
    }

}

contract ContractA {
    ContractB  public contractB;

    constructor() public {
        contractB = new ContractB();
    }
}

contract ContractB {

    constructor() public {}

    function test() public view returns (bool){
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: I am trying to interact with a third party contract. As I said I can interact with Contract A, but I also want to interact with contractb that is inside Contract A. Sadly Contract A's code is not calling the function I want to use, so I was hoping I could call contractb directly.

when I interact with Contract A, I type contracta.function() in javascript, I was hoping for something like contracta.contractb.function(), but that did not work.

Comment: You can use the interface of contract B to interact with B, and if contract B doesn't define an interface you can write one based on its function.Then instantiate it with InterfaceName(contractB_address), and you can use the contractB functions.